# How to boot from USB flash drive on an HP with BIOS of INSYDEH20 v. 3.5

Tags: usb, bios, bootable-media, hp-laptop

I rebooted many times with known-good USB flash drives in different ports. When I get to the boot choice (hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> at BIOS splash screen, follow prompt OR just <kbd>F9</kbd> at BIOS splash screen) I see the internal hard drive, a blank but selectable line, then CD/DVD drive.

I've gone into the BIOS and there's no secure boot option or anything but I can get into the boot order and the USB flash drive shows up there.

Comment: Do you try `rufus` sooftware? Also you need to change the `UEFI` in the bios option, but be aware of that you may can't access your old operation system anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Select the blank line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This didn't work every time and I don't know why, but try it again. The time it did work I was saving time by loading up the USB ports with known-good USB flash drives. So then there were two blank entries. I tried the first one and now it's installing Windows 10.